# How to check if a member of a structure is empty if a vector is defined of structure type?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct A { int rollno; int emplyno; }; 

int main()
{
   vector<A> obj;
   obj.push_back({10,112});
   if (obj.rollno == 0) // error
   {
      cout << "rollno is empty"<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: You know you can make your code even less readable if you put **everything** on a single line with no spaces.

Comment: Read the introduction to vectors in your favourite book.

Answer (score 1):

You need access the struct within your vector. You can do this by index:

```
if ((obj.size() > 0) && (obj[0].rollno == 0))
{
    std::cout  << "rollno is empty" << std::endl;
}
```

If you need to check ALL instances of `A` inside the vector, you can use a loop:

```
for (const A &a : obj)
{
    if (a.rollno == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Employee '" << a.emplyno << "' has an empty rollno" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vector is not an instance of `A`. It has no member `rollno`. Therefore the line with the comment is ill formed.

Instead, the vector is a container that holds a sequence of instances of `A`. It seems to me that you wish to access the first (and only) element of the vector. As you can see from the documentation of vector, you can access the first element using the `front` member function.